# Windows Mobile 10 showing scheduled notification without correct app name and icon

Tags: notifications, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, windows-phone-sl-8.1

I developed a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 application and before the Windows 10 update everything was working fine.

On Windows 10 Mobile whenever I receive a notification (sent using  `ScheduledToastNotification` and the `ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().AddToSchedule(scheduledToast)` method) it shows an error image instead of the app icon and a weird title instead of the app name as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Do you create  ScheduledToastNotification using XML content or NotificationsExtensions? You need to set your app name and icon explicitly in the ScheduledToastNotification's content.

Comment: I use XML content with ToastTemplateType.ToastText02. So I need to use the XmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName method and then set title and icon? Which tag name should I use to do thath?

Comment: Not sure, I prefer to use [NotificationExtensions](https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/NotificationsExtensions) library, but you can find examples for you case [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868254.aspx).

Comment: @AlessioCancian What's the OS version of your device? And the target SDK version. Have you tried the 14393 SDK and Mobile OS?